# Using `greenlet` as decorator

Tags: python, asynchronous, decorator, greenlets

Would it make sense to use `greenlet.greenlet` as a decorator, converting a regular function to a greenlet as follows:

```
from greenlet import greenlet

@greenlet
def f(args):
  # ...
  z = g.switch(u)
  # ...

@greenlet
def g(args):
  # ...

def main(args):
  # ...
  y = f.switch(x)
  # ...
```

Of course, I assume that I plan to use functions `f` and `g` only as greenlets.

Are there any hidden traps or other disadvantages to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no traps.

```
@greenlet
def g(args):
    # ...
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
def g(args):
    # ...

g = greenlet(g)
```